pymysql use commit still can't insert
Even using the commit() with pymysql, insert statement has no effect.
Hi, this is my first time posting here, and I hope someone can solve my problem.
I am using VS2022 to compile the following code in a Python 3.12 environment:
import pymysql

conn_test = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='****', charset='utf8', db='pythonTest', autocommit=True)

with conn_test.cursor() as cursor:
    1
    sql_insert = """
        INSERT INTO Members (Name, Height, Weight) VALUES
        ('Tony', 170, 56),
        ('Dawn', 167, 40),
        ('Jack', 185, 83);
    """
    cursor.execute(sql_insert)

    conn_test.commit()

conn_test.close()

I have already confirmed that the pymysql.connect command works correctly, and I have used it to create the 'members' table.
import pymysql

conn_test = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='****', charset='utf8', db='pythonTest')

with  conn_test.cursor() as cursor:
    sql_create = """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Members(
    ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Name varchar(20),
    Height int(6),
    Weight int(6)
    );
    """

    cursor.execute(sql_create)

    conn_test.commit()

conn_test.close()

I can see that the 'members' table was created using MySQL Workbench, but no matter how many times I refresh or rerun the code, the 'members' table doesn't contain data like Tony and others.
Since I'm not very familiar with pymysql, I'm not sure where the problem is. Could anyone help me solve this issue?
===2024/10/19 Update===
Hello everyone, I’ve been dealing with other matters during this time, so I apologize for not responding earlier. Here’s an update with the current Insert statement code, along with an image of the execution result.
import pymysql

conn_test = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='exagger2024SQL', charset='utf8', db='pythonTest', autocommit=True)

with conn_test.cursor() as cursor:
    1
    sql_insert = """
        INSERT INTO pythonTest.Members (ID, Name, Height, Weight) VALUES
        (1, 'Tony', 170, 56),
        (2, 'Dawn', 167, 40),
        (3, 'Jack', 185, 83)
    """
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql_insert)

        conn_test.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        conn_test.rollback()

        print(e);

conn_test.close()


As you can see, this piece of code doesn’t seem to show any errors, because if there were compilation errors, the 'try' and 'except' should have caught them, but they didn’t.
At the same time, the SQL database still doesn’t have any data like Tony and others.
Since I’m new to this, I’m feeling a bit lost. I really hope I can resolve this issue. In addition to continuing my research, I sincerely ask for your help. Thank you guys.

It looks like you forgot about ID column. It should be autoincrement or explicitly included in INSERT

I would expect the INSERT to fail. Unable to test because MySQL isn't (yet) supported on macOS Sequoia

@SIGHUP I'm using MySQL 8.4 on MacOS Sequoia. I installed it using Homebrew.

@BillKarwin I referred to the MySQL documentation that suggests that MySQL is not currently supported on Sequoia.

@Kadet Thank you, I added the ID values to my Insert statement, but it still doesn't work.

If there is no rows then maybe error is logged or exception is thrown ?
cursor.execute returns a number of affected rows, you can display this and display somethong after to confirm that python executes this line .
You can skip ';' at the end of insert statement (on examples there is no ; in statements)
